# How do I make SEO friendly URLs from my PHP pages?

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm pretty new to this and was wondering how to turn my site URLs into SEO friendly URLs using .htaccess and mod_rewrite?

My URLs take the form `mydomain.com/index.php?pid=1&pagename=Some Page`

I would like it be `mydomain.com/Some Page`

OR

`mydomain.com/somepage.html`

I know this is possible with mod_rewrite and .htaccess, but I'm having trouble finding an exact answer on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Check out this link http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 2):

You can find many tutos when you are searching over the web (or even more specifically on http://www.stackoverflow.com).

For instance, you can find this [good tutorial](http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/mod_rewrite.html).

Namely, you have to use conditions **RewriteCond** (one or more) and then add the rewriting you want to do with **RewriteRule**.

For instance, let say you want to redirect users to another domain (this is a dummy example, there are probably better ways to handle this):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/HTML2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /HTML2/$1
```